# How does Bore work?

Tags: borderlands-2

Bore is a skill that lets your bullets pierce through enemies dealing bonus damage to subsequent enemies hit.  It's description says

> Each additional target takes +100% bullet damage

Does this mean the +100% is cumulative (+100% for the second target, +200% to the third target, etc) or is it just a flat double damage after the first?  For that matter, is there a limit to how many targets a shot can pierce?

It also mentions this does not affect rockets and other special types of projectiles.  What projectiles does it not affect?

Comment: Why would passing through a target make your bullet MORE powerful??

Comment: @bwarner, as sir hammerlock says, because you're a badass

Comment: @bwarner because Borderlands.

Answer (score 5):

The bonus from piercing is cumulative. Presumably there is some upper limit to the bonus, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Yep. Just confirmed. First target takes base damage, second target takes x2, third takes x3.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that there's an upper limit, considering there's a B0re glitch on BNK-3R and other bosses that instantly kills them.

Answer (score 0):

It just keeps adding up there is no limit if you want prof go to the bunker and hit that circle part on the bottom off him and if you do it correctly it should one shot him ( I one shot him on op8 with a level 0 starting pistol

Comment: You could also do it with Hyperius